# Help with connector part numbers

Tags: connector

I need a really small 2-pin connector, a cable connector on one side, and a surface-mount jack on the other.  These two items at AllElectronics are pretty close:

- [Small Battery Connector, 2mm spacing](http://www.allelectronics.com/make-a-store/item/SBC-1/SMALL-BATTERY-CONNECTOR-WHITE/-/1.html)
- [Header for Small Battery Connector](http://www.allelectronics.com/make-a-store/item/SBH-1/HEADER-FOR-SMALL-BATTERY-CON-2MM-SPACING-WHITE/-/1.html)

What is the general name for these two items, so I can search Digikey or Molex?  And anyone know the exact part numbers of the above parts?  (AllElectronics doesn't know)

Update:

As per jluciani's awesome answer, these are definitely JST parts.  Mouser doesn't carry JST, but [Digikey does](http://search.digikey.com/scripts/DkSearch/dksus.dll?Detail&name=455-1704-ND) as does AlliedElec.   And it looks like [JST](http://www.jst.com/) makes SMT variants of the PCB mount header as well as small pitch connectors too.

Answer (score 7, accepted):

Those are headers and receptacles.

The parts in the pictures look like the common 2mm battery connectors
made by JST. If those connectors will work then I would search
for JST and 2 pins and 2mm pitch. The exact pn's for the TH
parts should be

- B2B-PH-K-S for a top entry header
- S2B-PH-K-S for a side entry header
- PHR-2 for a cable mount recptacle (without contacts)
  The contacts are SPH-002T-P0.5L for the 24-28AWG crimp

You may want to double check those pn's at Digikey and Mouser.

Connectors are one place where all the search engines fall short.
The printed catalog can sometimes be a lot quicker.

Comment: Yup, this looks pretty much spot on, thanks!  I thought JST was a connector style, not a manufacturer, as I'd only seen them referred to in the context of the 0.1" pitch connectors used for things like servo cabling.

Comment: You're welcome. You asked the right question at the right time. I just finished two Li-ion charger boards that use the JST connectors ;) Pics at http://tinyurl.com/yfs3ws3

Comment: The price for the crimping tool is laugh-out-loud hilarious. I'm sure you can just use a regular crimping tool or needle-nose pliers and save yourself $430 or so. :-)

Comment: The prices are high for hobbyists but those are professional tools. The design cost, documentation cost, manufacturing cost is spread over very small production runs. The weak dollar does not help.

I do a fair number of header crimps so I bought the Tyco (formerly
Amp) tool when it was on sale at Newark for around $250. Ratcheting
mechanism insures that all crimps are the same. The two piece die crimps the wire and strain-relief in the same pass. 

For terminals I do not use often I would use needle-nose plies and solder the crimp.